# Parachain not syncing with peers

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator, block, bootnode, sync

An instance is already running a parachain collator node and is producing block.

```
Is collating: yes
[Relaychain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWLhkaoFSGV2JfXea1BGTEAv2R5PE4v2b1nHZMo1ZGtXDG
[Relaychain]  Highest known block at #2080175
[Relaychain] Unable to bind RPC server to 127.0.0.1:9934. Trying random port.
[Relaychain] Listening for new connections on 127.0.0.1:8787.
[Parachain]   Local node identity is: 12D3KooWKgc4sx9atvXWksbsVtmHTS8Km48zXVJ1eeMgU1Keuxxx
[Parachain]  Highest known block at #106120
[Parachain] Unable to bind RPC server to 0.0.0.0:9933. Trying random port.
[Parachain] Listening for new connections on 0.0.0.0:8788.
[Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2080176 (0x4198…2361)
[Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2080177 (0x57e4…cbcd)
[Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0x4198af66d84a05fe8d1d27cf8f7df30c694a10033187c104de80df2a491c2361 at=0x8eca06571a2dbef7c6b5c4a7753db8f6d25e62a52304e4163e218b22ebf9597a
Accepted a new tcp connection from 172.31.1.116:36660.
[Relaychain]  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/3.xx.xx.53/tcp/7676/ws/p2p/12D3KooWLhkaoFSGV2JfXea1BGTEAv2R5PE4v2b1nHZMo1ZGtxxx
[Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0x57e43d64681b435fe6747815882cec49614ba1016d3d5ddcd3bad72efd74cbcd at=0x8eca06571a2dbef7c6b5c4a7753db8f6d25e62a52304e4163e218b22ebf9597a
```

While starting another chain, I used the following as bootnode

```
/ip4/3.xx.xx.53/tcp/7677/ws/p2p/12D3KooWKgc4sx9atvXWksbsVtmHTS8Km48zXVJ1eeMgU1Keuxxx
```

Started another node with `--bootnode $BOOTNODE` but this is the part of log which shows only relay chain is connected to peers but not parachain

```
[Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2080239 (0x0e33…c7cd)
[Relaychain]  Idle (13 peers), best: #2080239 (0x0e33…c7cd), finalized #2080236 (0xbcd8…bcd4), ⬇ 27.0kiB/s ⬆ 85.8kiB/s
[Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0de0…a7c2), finalized #0 (0x0de0…a7c2), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
[Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2080240 (0x7a79…eebf)
[Relaychain]  Idle (13 peers), best: #2080240 (0x7a79…eebf), finalized #2080236 (0xbcd8…bcd4), ⬇ 12.2kiB/s ⬆ 8.3kiB/s
[Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0de0…a7c2), finalized #0 (0x0de0…a7c2), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
[Relaychain]  Idle (13 peers), best: #2080240 (0x7a79…eebf), finalized #2080237 (0xb4e2…fa9a), ⬇ 17.8kiB/s ⬆ 53.9kiB/s
[Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2080241 (0xc61c…72eb)
[Parachain]  Idle (0 peers), best: #0 (0x0de0…a7c2), finalized #0 (0x0de0…a7c2), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
[Relaychain]  Idle (13 peers), best: #2080241 (0xc61c…72eb), finalized #2080237 (0xb4e2…fa9a), ⬇ 8.1kiB/s ⬆ 12.4kiB/s
[Relaychain] ✨ Imported #2080242 (0x01d7…88a5)
```

While relay chain's block are being synced but parachain block is not imported and always stays at genesis block.

Comment: Is the ip address really from your machine where the node is running? And are you sure that the port is right? Do you have the port open in your firewall?

Comment: Yes the ip address is from the machine. Yes port is also right. Not sure about firewall tho. But the thing is for relay chain it shows
`
[Relaychain]  Discovered new external address for our node: /ip4/3.xx.xx.53/tcp/7676/ws/p2p/12D3KooWLhkaoFSGV2JfXea1BGTEAv2R5PE4v2b1nHZMo1ZGtxxx
`
And but for parachain it shows nothing like this

Comment: @SudipGhimire hi! Have you found any solution for this? I am facing similar issue after upgrading my code base to polkadot-v0.9.29

Comment: Same here for upgrading the codebase to 0.9.26

Comment: Please open an issue on Github w/ all the info / logs you have. Thank you! There's one https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/12704 which I'm investigating right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add keys in the `parachain`.If you are making private network , then you need to add `aura` or `babe keys`(any one of them present in your code) in the `customSpec` and insert them in the `rpc calls` of the explorer in the `parachain`.